# Using Google Checkout, can I add items to the cart with text links?

Tags: google-checkout

Demo here using buttons
http://checkout.google.com/seller/gsc/v2/demo/index.html

I want to use, if possible text links in place of input buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Shopping_Cart_Overview.html), it looks like you can use a `div` as your Add To Cart button, which could be styled to look like a link.

[The Shopping Cart wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Shopping_Cart_Customizing_Shopping_Cart_Widget.html) should also be helpful.